# How can I write colored quote with icon in markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

This is my first time to see a colored quote with icon in https://github.com/rome/tools/blob/main/npm/rome/README.md. How can I do that?

[image]

As far as I tested I copied and pasted its original source code into gist but it resulted this in preview.

[image]

Comment: It seems not to work in preview. I tested both, in a gist and in a GitHub repo, the preview looks like your screenshot and the saved file looks correct.